# error in 'order by' in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have select query which I need to order by ascending order. Column has `varchar` datatype so I need to convert it to `int`. My query is working fine but there is some situation when the user needs to enter such values '121-1' so it gives an error on select query

> 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '121-2' to data type int.'

So is there any solution to ignore this error even on entering such values('121-1'). ?
Following is my query

```
SELECT ( [casetype] + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), caseno) 
         + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Year(Getdate())) )AS CaseNo, 
       caseno_id, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [filedate], 103)            AS DateOfFilling, 
       disrtictfrom, 
       tbl_recordrequisition.compname, 
       tbl_recordrequisition.respname, 
       casestage, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), nextdate, 103)              AS NextDate, 
       tbl_recordrequisition.remarks 
FROM   tbl_recordrequisition 
ORDER  BY LEFT(caseno_id, 2) ASC, 
          RIGHT(caseno_id, 4) ASC, 
          Cast(( Replace(Replace(caseno_id, LEFT(caseno_id, 3), ''), RIGHT( 
                 caseno_id, 5), 
                 '') ) 
               AS INT) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isnumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) fuction prior to casting to determine if value can be casted to `int`.

Something like

```
case when isnumeric(...) = 1 then cast(... as int) else 0 end
```

To avoid copypasting your long expression you can previously pre-calculate it using `outer apply`.

```
from   tbl_recordrequisition 
    outer apply (select  Replace(Replace(caseno_id, LEFT(caseno_id, 3), ''), 
                         RIGHT(caseno_id, 5), '') as Value) as CALC
order  by LEFT(caseno_id, 2) ASC, 
          RIGHT(caseno_id, 4) ASC, 
          case when isnumeric(CALC.Vaule) = 1 then cast(CALC.Value as int) else 0 end asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query helped me

```
order by left(CaseNo_ID,2) asc ,right(CaseNo_ID,4) asc, (select CAST((tbl_RecordRequisition.CaseNo) as int)  where tbl_RecordRequisition.CaseNo not like '%-%' ) asc
```

Thanks all